# ssh connection when not logged on

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

I am trying to set up a Ubuntu web server so far everything works but i ran into one problem.
I installed OpenSSH to be able to connect from my windows PC via Putty to the server, but this only works when i first logon with one of the user on the server itself.
So whenever i restart the server for some reason i have to run down to the basement to login so i can use ssh.

You can imagine this is not the way to go. So what am i'm doing wrong? Do i have to set somewhere that OpenSSH must run when the server starts? ...

Comment: Is the service running on system startup? (check rclevels)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try commenting the `ListenAddress` parameter on `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, restart your computer and see if you can connect from your Windows PC, without first having to login to Ubuntu.

If not please post the output of `grep ssh /var/log/auth.log`

Comment: ListenAddress is commented out.

Comment: Sep 30 11:03:29 #### sshd[442]: reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for pc-####.local [10.15.10.22] failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
Sep 30 11:03:36 #### sshd[442]: Accepted password for #### from 10.15.10.22 port 52246 ssh2
Sep 30 11:03:36 #### sshd[442]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user #### by (uid=0)
Sep 30 11:03:52 #### sshd[442]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user ####
Sep 30 11:38:26 #### sshd[645]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Sep 30 11:38:26 #### sshd[645]: Server listening on :: port 22.

Comment: Could the problem be that i'm connected to wifi for the moment? And the wifi connection doesn't go up before i login?

Comment: @Dazz yes, that's your real problem.  Fixing it to start the wifi connection when the computer starts probably needs a new question with what tool you used to configure the wireless, etc.

Comment: Yeap thats your problem. Any possibility of getting an Ethernet cable down to the basement and connect it to the switch your access point is connected to? :)